# qmake copy files created while building

Tags: qt, copy, installation, qmake

I've got a library qmake project:

```
QT       += gui

TARGET = qturtle
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += QTURTLE_LIBRARY

SOURCES += qturtle.cpp

HEADERS += qturtle.h\
        qturtle_global.h

docMake.commands = doxygen;
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += docMake
PRE_TARGETDEPS += docMake
QMAKE_DISTCLEAN += $$PWD/html/ -r
QMAKE_DISTCLEAN += doxygen_sqlite3.db

unix {
    docInstall.path = /usr/share/doc/qturtle
    docInstall.files = $$PWD/html/

    headerInstall.files = $$HEADERS
    headerInstall.path = /usr/include/qturtle

    target.path = /usr/lib

    INSTALLS += docInstall
    INSTALLS += target
    INSTALLS += headerInstall
}
```

`docMake` runs `doxygen` in the project directory, and creates the 'html' directory and its contents ( during build!)
'html' and its contents now should be copied to /usr/share/doc/qturtle, using the `INSTALL` variable.
BUT: qmake doesn't generate any code for `docInstall` install, because `$$PWD/html` and its contents do not exist during makefile generation. Could anybody tell me how to avoid this problem, or do I have to use `cp`?

Thanks in advance,
Marius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to address this problem.

### Not to check againt the initially empty directory

```
docInstall.CONFIG += no_check_exist directory
```

Since this directory will be created on the fly, I would personally opt for this.

### Create the directory explicitly

```
createDirs.commands = $$QMAKE_MKDIR $$PWD/html
```

This could be done either in a target or even in a `system("$$QMAKE_MKDIR $$PWD/html")` call, depending on your needs.

Comment: Just one last question: where did you find this? :D

Comment: @marius_linux: in my brain. :-) Nah, source code... Btw, s/againt/against/ in the text.

Comment: OK, well I think that's what I'm going to do next time :D
THX very much