# qmake INSTALLS for a file not existing yet

Tags: qt, qmake

Suppose I have a test.pro file with content as followings

```
unix {
    inspro.path = /tmp
    inspro.files += test.pro
}
!isEmpty(inspro.path) INSTALLS += inspro

unix {
    insdoc.path = /tmp
    insdoc.files += test.txt
}
!isEmpty(insdoc.path) INSTALLS += insdoc
```

Running `qmake test.pro` results in a Makefile. The file, test.pro, exists already, and the created Makefile contains install_inspro and uninstall_inspro for the file test.pro:

```
install_inspro: first FORCE
        @test -d $(INSTALL_ROOT)/tmp || mkdir -p $(INSTALL_ROOT)/tmp
        $(QINSTALL) /home/jianz/test/pro/test.pro $(INSTALL_ROOT)/tmp/test.pro

uninstall_inspro: FORCE
        -$(DEL_FILE) -r $(INSTALL_ROOT)/tmp/test.pro
        -$(DEL_DIR) $(INSTALL_ROOT)/tmp/
```

However, corresponding install_insdoc and install_insdoc are created if and only if the file test.txt exists.

In the case that the file test.txt is created as part of QMAKE_POST_LINK, is there a way to force qmake to create install_insdoc and uninstall_insdoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a custom install target CONFIG directive to help with this.  Add:

```
    insdoc.CONFIG += no_check_exist
```

Documented at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#installs
More details and caveats at https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake#Custom_install_config
Related Q/A: [qmake copy files created while building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671415/qmake-copy-files-created-while-building)